# Delete Association for has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In a has_many :through relationship, is there an easy way to delete an association?

If I have the models:

deal.rb

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_events
  has_many :events, :through => :deal_events
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_events
  has_many :deals, :through => :deal_events
end
```

deal_event.rb

```
class DealEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal
  belongs_to :event
end
```

and in the console:

```
deal = Deal.first
event = Event.first
deal.events << event
```

I know that if I want to destroy the association for both deal and event, I know I can call

```
deal.events.destroy(event)
event.deals.destroy(deal)
```

but deal.deal_events and event.deal_events still contain the deal_event.. is there a cleaner way to do this and completely remove the relationship and let the event remain in Event.all and the deal remain in Deal.all? Thanks

### Update

The Rails console fooled me..

After I did this

```
deals.events << event
```

Rails was not entering a query since the query for event.deal_events had already been executed so this..

```
1.9.3-p327 :020 > event.deal_events
 => []
```

was happening, but when I exited and entered rails console again, then the query is executed..

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > event.deal_events
  DealEvent Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "deal_events".* FROM "deal_events" WHERE "deal_events"."event_id" = 1
 => [#<DealEvent id: 2, deal_id: 1, event_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-15 21:37:24", updated_at: "2013-01-15 21:37:24">, #<DealEvent id: 3, deal_id: 1, event_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-15 21:37:38", updated_at: "2013-01-15 21:37:38">]
```

I'll mark @ChapleyWatson as the answer because it pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your parent Model

```
before_destroy :clear_my_association


# model stuff

private

  def clear_my_association

    self.my_association_model.clear

  end
```